# Why is there no enumeration concept in C++ 20?

Tags: c++, type-traits, std, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to update some older code to the coming C++20 language using current GCC10.

I was not able to update some templates because they used a `std::enable_if<std::is_enum_v<T>>` condition and there is no `std::enumeration` concept defined in C++20.

Of course I can define my own concept but still it makes me wonder why C++20 does not implement all existing type traits as concepts.

Why is this? Did I miss something important?

Comment: Why does there need to be an enumeration concept?

Comment: @Barry because its convinient.

Comment: @Cortex What convenience does it provide? Being slightly shorter?

Comment: @Barry Well, clearly alot of the concepts are 'unessecary' but I think its syntax is alot cleaner. template <std::enumeration E> vs template <typename E, std::enable_if<std::is_enum_v<E>>. Ofcourse that is just my opionion.

Comment: @Cortex That's a false choice, you could write `<typename E> requires std::is_enum_v<E>`.

Comment: I would like to write `template <std::enumeration T> void f(T t);` which AFAIK is not possible without a concept, is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `enumeration` concept because there was never a specific intent to create a concept to match every type trait. Or even most of them.

The C++20 concept library was, more or less, based on what was needed to make the Ranges library work. It focuses on things concepts are good at, like asking "what can I do with this type?" You can ask if you can default-construct a `T` or copy/move one, and such. You're not constraining things on what a type is, but what you're going to do with it.

A concept like `enumeration` just isn't a very useful constraint. Remember: from a logical perspective, if a template constrains a parameter, then it should only use that parameter in accord with that constraint. So if you have a function that takes a default-constructible `T`, then that function should only use `T` by default constructing one (though nothing syntactically stops you from violating that, it's generally considered poor form).

To be `integral` or `floating_point` requires that the type be one of those fundamental types, which brings with it all of the expressiveness that those types provide.

But what could you do with `enumeration` *by itself*? You can default-construct one (though whether this represents a legit enum value or not isn't apparent, so it's not clear what you'd do with it), you can assign and compare it (though even comparison can be overloaded/`delete`d), you can play games with its underlying type. But that's about it.

If some `T` is an enumeration, that doesn't mean that the `T` has any particular enum fields. So the primary feature of an enumeration is lost to you if your constraint is simply that it is an enumeration.

That doesn't mean it can't come up. But just because a constraint occasionally comes up doesn't mean it rises to the level of being a concept.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. In my case I hit some templates that access a custom enumeration RTTI framework. This actually requires the used types to be enumerations. I don't think I could re-condition this more concept-like.

Comment: We have a use case where enums need to be converted from string in a generic function. The enum 'specialization' routes to the integer one.

Comment: Haskell has shown some good uses for an enumeration concept

Comment: I feel a lot of these reasons could equally be leveraged at `type_traits` (or more abstractly, enums in general), but there *is* an enum trait.

Answer (score 1):

Perusing the header design documents I came across this paper:

- [Sutton and Stroustrup; Design of Concept Libraries for C++](https://www.stroustrup.com/sle2011-concepts.pdf)

Particularly they state in the abstract:

> **constraints** are predicates on static properties of a type, and **concepts** are abstract specifications of an algorithm’s syntactic and semantic requirements.

And later on:

> **Constraints** are closely related to the notion of **type traits**

To put it another way, traits are ruled out, and it could be reasoned that there *is no* `enum` concept for the same reasons there *is* an `enum` trait.

I feel the bigger question is why does the `int` concept exist. This is clearly heading away from abstract territory, though that's another question and I suspect the answer lies in practicalities.

For anyone here looking, traits can be used as concepts via e.g.:

```
template<typename T> concept IsEnum = std::is_enum_v<T>;
```

Ultimately, I found it helps to differentiate the header `concepts`, which is full of very abstract concepts, from the C++ keyword `concept`, which can be leveraged to do many things.